# Normalization of financial price to use as input in a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, normalization, standardization

I'm looking for the best method to normalize/standardize financial prices in order to use them as inputs for my neural network. As you probably know financial prices do not follow a normal distribution and you can't even know the max or min needed for the normalization as in the test set there could be a price higher or lower than the ones in the training set.

So I thought that I could standardize my datas trough a rolling window so the price standardized at time $t$ is computed as:
\begin{equation}
p'_{t}=\frac{p_{t}-E(p_{t-k:t})}{\sigma(p_{t-k:t})}
\end{equation}

where with $p_{t-k:t}$ I mean succession of prices within the window of length k (from the period t-k to t)

Does it make sense? Is there any reasearch that I could study in deep? I've found the adaptive normalization method but it's too advanced for what I have to do (my goal is not to predict prices, so it's just an input variable that could help the model)

Comment: What exactly is Pt - k:t, is that a rolling window within the data?

Comment: Yes, just edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Financial prices are, in general, not stationary. However, for a number of theoretical and empirical reasons we do think that *log-returns* (differences of $\log($prices$)$) are closer to stationary. Often, they are considered "close enough" to allow inference.  The one exception to prices not being close to stationary *might* be prices which tend to be mean-reverting due to industrial production changing slowly: commodity prices, for example.

There is a major caveat to all this, however: we know that prices and log-returns of all assets (including commodities) exhibit persistent and time-varying variance. The correction is to model the conditional variance of log-returns using something like a GARCH model.

You may not need to use a GARCH model to get usable inferences; however, you should definitely be working with log-returns. I have seen enough presentations (in industry and academia) ended on the opening slide when somebody did not use log-returns. Even using standard returns often earns some skepticism.

Comment: Yes, I know in fact I already use log-returns as an input variable. But daily prices offer different values as the maximum price or the minimum price: what to do to insert even those variables in a neural net? Do you mean I have to use log-returns for each type of price (i.e. log-returns of the time series of max prices ...)?

Comment: You could maybe use something different, but that would depend on what you are trying to estimate since there are only a few instances where using something else is justifiable.

Comment: I'm working on a reinforcement learning model for trading with a DQN, and I would like to include even  maximum/minimum price as inputs

Comment: Depending on how you structure your other inputs, you could specify the max and min as prices (probably troublesome) or as log-returns versus the opening price or last price (more useful when comparing to volatility estimates).

Answer (score 3):

There is no one right answer as how to normalize data. I found this good article by [Nayak et al. (2014)](http://www.mirlabs.org/ijcisim/regular_papers_2014/IJCISIM_24.pdf) that give different normalization techniques for financial time series data. I haven't seen your specific technique before. In general I think the issue is that while you account for the data loss of a normal min/max normalization with the lokal window $k$, over long periods of time, you have the same issue as min/max that your data can grow outside of the window. I personally would start with z-score normalization (described in Nayak et al., 2014).

$p'_t = \frac{p_t-E(p))}{\sigma(p)}$

I think that'll probably suit you well, but play around with other ideas depending on the range of your data.